# Limiting the user to enter the characters and also to convert the each entered letter into capital letter in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, text, uitextfield

I am having 4 text fields in which I want to put two limitations simultaneously. One is that the user should be able to type in only capital letters with the maximum character limit to 2 only. My code for this is as follows:-

```
  - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range 
   replacementString:(NSString *)string {

// Below logic is for All 4 Modifer Textfields
// we are restrict the user to enter only max 2 characters in modifier textfields.
if (textField==txt_modifier1 || textField==txt_modifier2 || textField==txt_modifier3 || 
textField==txt_modifier4) {
    textField.text = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range
                                                             withString:[string 
    uppercaseStringWithLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]];
    NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
    return (newLength > 2) ? NO : YES;

}
return YES;
```

}

this is not functioning properly as it is appending one more character as I type in any character and also not limiting the number of characters to 2. Please suggest a way to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're manually updating the text in your textfield and then sending `YES` back (which then appends the characters a second time). Then, you're usingthe new text with the replacement string to compare it to two (which, then appends your characters again) ...

Try this:

```
if (...) {
    NSString *result = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range
                                                               withString:string.uppercaseString];
    if (result.length <= 2)
        textField.text = result;
    return NO;
}
return YES;
```

Comment: and if I also want to restrict the user from entering the special characters also then what possible condition I could set here.

Comment: You can use an inverted `NSCharacterSet` for that. For example, if you don't want any characters other than capitals, you can put this above `NSString *result`: `if ([string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet capitalizedLetterCharacterSet] invertedSet]].count > 1) return NO;`

Answer (score 0):

For limiting the number of characters and capitalizing it in your UITextField, use this code block

```
     -(BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string { 

            textField.text = [textField.text capitalizedString];
            if(textField.text.length >= 3 && range.length == 0) 
            {
                 return NO; 
            }
            else 
            {
                 return YES;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use this one ...It may help you

```
  -(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
        if([string isEqualToString:[string capitalizedString]])
        {

            NSString *result = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range
                                                                       withString:string.uppercaseString];
            if (result.length <= 2)
                textField.text = result;
            return NO;
        }
        else
            return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

login`UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification`Make judgment here

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                          selector:@selector(textChanged:)
                                              name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification
                                            object:YOUR_TEXT_FIELD];

-(void)textChanged:(NSNotification *)notif {
    //to do your logic
}
```